# Drop down menu does not display when checkbox is checked

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my menu to collapse and expand with the use of only CSS. I've found this solution only and have looked over other forum posts and still am unable to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
.fullWidth {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
}
.imgfull {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.nav {
  float: right;
  margin: -22px 57px 0 0;
}
.nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 25px 0 0 -15px;
}
.nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 0 0 25px;
}
.nav ul li a {
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  color: #9a0000;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navlog {
  float: right;
  margin: 12px 50px 0 0;
}
.navlog ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.navlog ul li {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.navlog ul li a {
  background-color: #9a0000;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
.navlog ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.show-menu {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #19c589;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: none;
}
/*Hide checkbox*/

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .nav {
  display: block;
}
@media (max-width: 48.000em) {
  .nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 50px;
  }
  .nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: auto;
    position: static;
    display: none;
  }
  .nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .nav ul li:nth-of-type(odd) a {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  .nav ul li a {
    padding: 8px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: block;
  }
  .nav ul li,
  li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 48.000em) {
  .navlog {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 50px;
  }
  .navlog ul {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 -35px 0;
  }
  .navlog ul li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .navlog ul li:nth-of-type(odd) a {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  .navlog ul li a {
    padding: 8px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button"/>
<div class="nav">                       
  <ul class="show-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Application Process</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Rental Listings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tenant Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>  
</div>                      

<br clear="both"/>
```

Comment: try adding fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Only include minimal code that necessarily for reproducing the issue,  you might be able to find out the problem before posting it. Side note, targeting `input[type=checkbox]` isn't efficient at all, just use `#show-menu` and `#show-menu:checked` would be much better, since you already assigned the id for the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.show-menu` is the hidden item, not `.nav`.  You'll want to correct the following code:

```
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .nav .show-menu{
    display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2vmLwntc/

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .nav ul{
    display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ju51L5oh/